# How to audit terragrunt tree for modules and download them?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have an extensive terragrunt tree, with lots of `terragrunt.hcl` files. Each has a `source = "<some module>"` referencing some terraform module.

I am looking to audit my modules, both determining upon which modules we depend, as well as information about those modules.

Is there a native way to do this within terragrunt, or some external tool?

I started doing this in script, but it does get messy.

1. Run a `find . -name terragrunt.hcl` and then `awk` to get the value of `source = "<module>"`
2. Do some processing on the value of `<module>` to download it and get information about it.

The first part is doable, if messy. The second part is particularly messy, especially since it follows unique formats like `git::ssh::...` or other structures. These already are understood by the terraform-world tools, so I was hoping there is something that does this already.

Is there anything that can do (at least parts of) this for me?